# How to use the dynamic island(Live Activity) api in an existing app that still supports old iOS versions?

Tags: swift, objective-c, dynamic-island

I created a Widget & a LiveActivity extension in my app. My app still supports iOS 10 and it's a pure `objective-c` project.

So how I can use the `LiveActivity` API in my app.

I tried to import LiveActiveWidget.swift in my `objective-c` project.
When I create a swift file in my project and import the Widget file to it, it says:

> Compiling for iOS 10.0, but module 'xx' has a minimum deployment
> target of iOS 16.1

Then I import the "Widget-Swift.h" to an existing `objective-c` file, it says no such file, may be they are at a different target.

Answer (score -1):

you can integrate it by using swift bridging header,

**let me explain** ,

once you add live activity widget in project , you will able to see one swiftUI file for live activity's UI , now you need to create one swift file for 'ActivityAttributes' in swift , as well need to create one swift file where you will implement all needed methods and code for live activity , now crate bridging header to use your swift code in objective c project , import swift file in a obj-c view controller where you want to implement live activity and call needed functions according your feature flaw, I've implement same way in my project and **it's working well** .

Comment: The question is asking how to do this in a project with a deployment target of iOS 10. The answer should address the issues involved with using a modern extension in an app with a very old deployment target.

Comment: yes I'm having same scenario , also having Low deployment target , may be I forget to add it in answer on deployment , let me correct it